# amadeus affiliate search unknown error

Tags: php, api, amadeus

Hi I'm facing this problem when using affiliate search sandbox php module

I noticed that the currency part has error

```
Exception when calling DefaultApi->flightAffiliateSearch: [400] Error connecting to the API (https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/flights/affiliate-search?apikey=xxxxxx&origin=LON&destination=DUB&departure_date=2017-10-25&return_date=2017-11-28&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&max_price=44¤cy=EUR&mobile=0)
```

how can i solve this

Comment: I found that error from http_build_query command 
it converts the &curren  to that pattern

Comment: another problem was mobile=0
removing currency and mobile manually from request by unsetting them from queryParams array in file ApiClient  solved the problem 

but how to add currency and mobile now

Comment: solved part of mobile  , i think the system require mobile as string ,
so  in DefaultApi 
convert the mobile check condition to

// query params
        if ($mobile !== null) {
            $mobile = $mobile ? "true" : "false";
            $queryParams['mobile'] = $this->apiClient->getSerializer()->toQueryValue($mobile);

        }

just add the bollen to string condition ($mobile = $mobile ? "true" : "false";) before inject the mobile to url

Answer (score 0):

Repaired

in the ApiClient.php

before calling http_build_query

add this code to escape &curren to &\curren

```
if (isset($queryParams['currency']))
           {
               $queryParams['\currency'] = $queryParams['currency'];
               unset($queryParams['currency']);
            }
```